# Running a script that contain a image

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am creating a script for personal use and would like to insert an image in code, so when I run the program the script display the image on my end and my code below.

It is possible to insert and display the image inside the terminal with script?

My script(code) run in terminal, my OS is Linux(Ubuntu).

Comment: Gnome Terminal doesn't support images, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures

Comment: Look at [Zenity Manual - GNOME Library](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/)

Answer (score 0):

### w3mimgdisplay

The `w3m` web-browser provides a utility `w3mimgdisplay` that can be used to display images on some terminals. For example, you could run it as a bash `coproc`.

It's not very well documented but see information at:

- https://blog.z3bra.org/2014/01/images-in-terminal.html
- https://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg34447.html